# N1QL subquery in WHERE condition

Tags: arrays, subquery, sql++

```
SELECT * 
FROM `masterdata` AS T1
WHERE T1.`$Type` = "ProEvent"
  AND Id IN (SELECT RAW A.DocId AS Id 
             FROM `masterdata` AS T
             UNNEST T.List AS A
             WHERE T.`$Type` = "CustomerAutoList"
               AND T.CustId = "202479")
```

When subquery executed alone, returns the result in the below format

```
[
  "PromoEvent::506427_43_503934_157",
  "PromoEvent::506427_43_509843_157"
]
```

But when the subquery is given in "Where" condition in the main query, the result is empty

```
SELECT * 
FROM `masterdata` AS T1
WHERE T1.`$Type` = "ProEvent"
  AND Id IN (SELECT RAW A.DocId AS Id 
             FROM `masterdata` AS T
             UNNEST T.List AS A
             WHERE T.`$Type` = "CustomerAutoList"
               AND T.CustId = "202479")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work. Check Id value of ProEvent document.

Try the following query. If still has issue project docids and see those expected value then check where it eliminated.

```
WITH docids AS (ARRAY_FLATTEN((SELECT RAW a.List[*].DocId
                               FROM `masterdata` AS a
                               WHERE a.`$Type`="CustomerAutoList" AND a.CustId="202479")
                              ), 1)
SELECT t.*
FROM `masterdata` AS t
WHERE t.`$Type`="ProEvent"
AND t.Id IN docids;
```

If DocId is same as document key of "ProEvent"

```
SELECT t.*
FROM `masterdata` AS a
JOIN `masterdata` AS t ON KEYS a.List[*].DocId
WHERE a.`$Type`="CustomerAutoList" AND a.CustId="202479";
```